# SonarQube analysis failed to complete the review of this pull request on larger set of files

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, pull-request, sonarqube-scan

I Am using Github pull request plugin to run analysis on the Pull request. Recently i am seeing issues when there are huge number of file changes like 185 files seeing errors on Jenkins run like this.

```
INFO: Executing post-job GitHub Pull Request Issue Publisher
ERROR: SonarQube analysis failed to complete the review of this pull request
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create or update review comment in file file-path at line 93
```

This path changes randomly if i run multiple times.
Also this are additional errors which i couldn't make out.

```
Caused by: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: {"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"resource":"PullRequestReviewComment","code":"abuse","field":"base"}]
```

```
Caused by: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: Server returned HTTP response code: 422, message: 'Unprocessable Entity' for URL
```

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 422 for URL
```